# Implementing Reg. expression in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a question regarding implementing some predicates in prolog.(for regular expression.)
I need to implement 4 predicates

My implementation is

```
sublist( Sublist, List ) :- append( [_, Sublist, _], List ). %true if SubList is a sublist of a List
match(one(List),W) :- sublist(List,W). %true if there is a single occurence of List
match(opt(_),[]).  %true if there are 0 or 1 occurences of List
match(opt(List),W) :- sublist(List,W).
match(star(_),[]).  %true if there are 0 or more occurences of List
%more occurences
match(plus(List),W) :- sublist(List,W). %true if there are 1 or more occurences of List
%more occurences
```

Now, my problem is.

1. I have no idea how to implement more occurences.
2. If I wanted to call it like match([here would be more expressions],S), for example
   `length(S,3),match([star[1],opt[2,3]],S)` Would that work?

EDIT:
2) problem is easily fixable, I am just iterating through the list.

Comment: When is "true if there are 0 or more occurrences of List" ever intended to actually be false?

Comment: Probably not if I think about it. The main problem is now the 2nd point.

Comment: Actually not, I fixed the 2nd.

Answer (score 0):

Your "match(one(..." can use:

```
exactly_one_solution(Template, Goal) :-
    % Check whether more than 1 solution exists
    bagof(Template, limit(2, Goal), Solutions),
    Solutions = [Template].
```

And your "match(plus(..." can use the standard Prolog `once/1`, to ensure more-than-zero matches.

Comment: I think that my one(List,S) works. The goal is to have only one sublist. But what I wanna do is to for star try it more times, so for example, 
length(S,4),match(star([1,2]),S) would be        
S = [1,2,1,2];        
S = [1,2,"_","_"];